# Changing screen in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

So I started Skyrim and I noticed that the screen doesn't fully fit on my TV. I can't find an option to change this though. I have it on Xbox 360 and is there a way to make it fit the screen perfectly?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings>System Settings>Display> and play with the setting to see if that works. For most modern TVs the optimal resolution is named 1080i or 1080p depending on what device your using. It can also depend on whether you are using HDMI or AV.

Comment: did it work Bucky?